# Read CSS property of an element using JavaScript

Tags: javascript, css

So if there is a css file linked to a webpage like:

```
<link href="style.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
```

and i want to read a certain property, e.g a div has className='layout' and i want to read the details of this property using JavaScript, how can i do that?

I have searched a lot but almost have no luck, please suggest.

Comment: just use jquery, http://api.jquery.com/css/

Comment: actually the problem is, if <style> attribute is defined inside the document it just works easily. Now even with jQuery, i can set the value, or read inline values, not external css values... I just somehow want to read the properties of external css file which is applied on some element in document

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do you read CSS rule values with JavaScript?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/324486/how-do-you-read-css-rule-values-with-javascript)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You have got two options:

1. Manually enumerating and parsing the [`document.styleSheets`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/document.styleSheets) object (not recommended, unless you want to get all specific style properties defined by a certain selector).
2. Create an element matching the selector, and use the `getComputedStyle` or `currentStyle` (IE) method to get the property value.

In your example, attempt to get a certain property (let's say: `color`) of a div with `class="layout"`:

```
function getStyleProp(elem, prop){
    if(window.getComputedStyle)
        return window.getComputedStyle(elem, null).getPropertyValue(prop);
    else if(elem.currentStyle) return elem.currentStyle[prop]; //IE
}
window.onload = function(){
    var d = document.createElement("div"); //Create div
    d.className = "layout";                //Set class = "layout"
    alert(getStyleProp(d, "color"));       //Get property value
}
```

**Regarding comment at your question**, another function:
The function below will ignore inline style definitions of the current element. If you want to know the style definitions inherited from a stylesheet (without inherited style definitions of the parent elements), traverse the tree, and temporary wipe the `.cssText` property, as shown in the funcion below:

```
function getNonInlineStyle(elem, prop){
    var style = elem.cssText; //Cache the inline style
    elem.cssText = "";        //Remove all inline styles
    var inheritedPropValue = getStyle(elem, prop); //Get inherited value
    elem.cssText = style;     //Add the inline style back
    return inheritedPropValue;
}
```

Comment: thank you so much, it works in firefox, but somehow i get null when using chrome, is there something missing for chrome?

Comment: I'm surprised that the function worked in FireFox, because my function contained a typo. It's fixed now. Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/kDNFz/

Comment: actually i corrected it while testing, so yes it worked, but i can't seem to have the same result in chrome, it's a big problem.

Comment: @Johnydep Chrome seems not to apply style attributes until the element is rendered by adding it to the document tree. I have successfully tested the function by adding two lines, **see" http://jsfiddle.net/QFfLB/**

Comment: Will this also serve as an answer to [this older question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/324486/how-do-you-read-css-rule-values-with-javascript)?

Comment: @Blazemonger The questions are a bit different. The "[older question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/324486/how-do-you-read-css-rule-values-with-javascript)" requests access to all CSS properties that matches a given *selector* (could be more than one), while this question specifically asks for one specific CSS property for a given element.