# Using JavaScript/jQuery to display multiple CSS values on any given element

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I have a situation where a `div` has two CSS `display` properties. One is set to `none` and the other is set to `block`. However, `display: none` overrides `display: block` because of CSS specificity.

I can use JavaScript/jQuery to find out the `display` value of this element. In this given scenario, the result would be `none` because it is the overriding style. However, I would like to be able to retrieve all of the `display` values on this element. I want my JavaScript to return `none` as well as `block`.

Is this even possible?

Comment: Just curious on why you would want to do that

Comment: I'm working on a jQuery plugin that needs to use the `display` value on an element, ignoring all values of `none`. So in this example the plugin would use `block` as its value.

Answer (score 0):

You need to look at the class names for the element and look them up in the stylesheet.

See: [Read CSS property of an element using JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7894577/read-css-property-of-an-element-using-javascript)

Comment: I have looked at that, but it doesn't help with my problem.