# Adding important to css media queries

Tags: javascript, css, media-queries

I have a html code with inline css and also with css media queries
While running the inline css is not being replaced by media queries.
I need to find a way to add those !important in every style inside the media query dynamically (may be with js). Is there a way to do this other than traversing through to html content as string and finding the styles and adding it.
I have added a sample code for reference

```css
  body {
          background-color: yellow;
        }
        @media only screen and (max-width: 600px) {
          body {
            background-color: lightblue;
          }
        }
```

```html
    <body style="background-color:red;">
    </body>
```

Comment: No, you need a script, and I wouldn't loop and add _!important_ to your external CSS. Instead loop and remove the inline `style` attribute. `document.querySelectorAll('[style]')` will get you all that as inline styles.

Comment: FYI, inline CSS has a better specificity value than your css in media queries. I would also suggest try to remove style attribute as @LGSon mentioned above. Check this out for more information on specificity value https://css-tricks.com/specifics-on-css-specificity/

Comment: And `document.querySelectorAll('[style^="background-color"]')` all that also start with a given property. More here about the attribute selector: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Attribute_selectors

Comment: This post has a good starting point on how to deal with styles using script: https://stackoverflow.com/a/7894886/2827823

Answer (score 0):

remove inline css from `body` tag, as inline css has high specificity value

and try this, add important in media query as when screen size changes you need `lightblue` background color

```
body {
      background-color: yellow;
    }
    @media only screen and (max-width: 600px) {
      body {
        background-color: lightblue;
      }
    }
```

Comment: The `!important` is unnecessary if the inline style is removed. The media query comes after the basic selector, and whatever comes later overrides previous styles.

Comment: i can't remove the inline css. The html content comes from the server. I gave you an example of my scenario

Comment: then I think you need to do this,https://www.sitepoint.com/javascript-media-queries/