# get width of transformed: scaled element

Tags: javascript, jquery, width, scale, webkit-transform

I have 2 elemenets. One is scaled down in the CSS

```
.firstElement{
-webkit-transform:scale(.5,.5);
}
```

and the other is scaled inline by jQuery's

```
secondElement.animate({scale:.2, origin:[0,0])}
```

I need to get the width and height of the secondElement and the firstElement in pixels after they are scaled down.
I tried everything, Im really not sure why I cant get this. 
Anyone have any ideas?
Thanks

Comment: have a look at [calculate width of scaled element](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5834624/retrieve-width-height-of-a-css3-scaled-element#answer-5835579)

Answer (score 0):

```
var matrix = window.getComputedStyle(this).webkitTransform,
        data;
    if (matrix != 'none') {
        data = matrix.split('(')[1].split(')')[0].split(',');
    } else {
        data = [1,null,null,1];
    }
```

Code Courtesy : [CSS TRICKS](http://css-tricks.com/get-value-of-css-rotation-through-javascript/)

[**FIDDLE DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/vaibviad/zqyRH/65/)