# CSS transform scale and Javascript offsetHeight

Tags: javascript, css, css-transforms

I got a strange result of offsetHeight combining with scale transforming.
My simple HTML as below

```
  <body>
    <div id="id01">
      Some Text
    </div>
    <div id="id02" style="transform-origin: left top; transform: scale(2)">
      Some Text
    </div>
  </body>

  <script>
    var elem01 = document.getElementById('id01');
    var elem02 = document.getElementById('id02');
    alert(elem01.offsetHeight == elem02.offsetHeight);   // Always show true???
  </script>
```

On the screen the second `<div>` is bigger (twice) than the first `<div>`. Thus I expected second `<div>`'s offsetHeight should be greater than the first one.

My question is: Why `elem01.offsetHeight` always equals to `elem02.offsetHeight` in this case? The browser does not use `transform` to calculate element's `offsetHeight`?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The transform affects the pixel ratio not the actual amount of pixels in the DOM.

[This previous question has some insights and possible solutions.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5834624/retrieve-width-height-of-a-css3-scaled-element)